# Load Url on Pepper's Tablet

Tags: pepper

I'm trying to load a website on Pepper like "www.google.com"

I'm sure we are connected on the same network. I've tried doing "http://www.google.com" too on the ShowApp Dialog.

I've seen this guide: http://kokorobot.com/2016/08/08/how-to-use-pepper-tablet

```py
class MyClass(GeneratedClass):

    def __init__(self):
        GeneratedClass.__init__(self)

    def onLoad(self):
        self.isRunning = False

    def onUnload(self):
        self.isRunning = False

    def _getTabletService(self):
        tabletService = None
        try:
            tabletService = self.session().service("ALTabletService")
        except Exception as e:
            self.logger.error(e)
        return tabletService

    def onInput_onStart(self):
        if self.isRunning:
            return # already running, nothing to do
        self.isRunning = True
        # We create TabletService here in order to avoid
        # problems with connections and disconnections of the tablet during the life of the application
        tabletService = self._getTabletService()
        appName = self.packageUid()
        state = False
        if appName:
            if tabletService:
                if tabletService.loadApplication(appName):
                    tabletService.loadUrl("www.google.com")                    self.logger.info("Successfully set application: %s" % appName)
                    tabletService.showWebview()
                    state = True
                else:
                    self.logger.warning("Got tablet service, but failed to set application: %s" % appName)
            else:
                self.logger.warning("Couldn't find tablet service, so can't set application: %s" % appName)
        if state:
            self.onSuccess()
        else:
            self.onFailure()
```

Comment: what is the issue you are experiencing? Is the tablet giving an error, showing a white screen, or a black screen?
What is your console output?

Comment: White screen, 404 error not found nginx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to show a web consider using the box "Show Web View" instead. I've found that Show App gives more trouble than it's worth it.

```
class MyClass(GeneratedClass):

    def __init__(self):
        GeneratedClass.__init__(self)

    def onLoad(self):
        pass

    def onUnload(self):
        pass

    def _getTabletService(self):
        tabletService = None
        try:
            tabletService = self.session().service("ALTabletService")
        except Exception as e:
            self.logger.error(e)
        return tabletService

    def _getAbsoluteUrl(self, partial_url):
        import os
        subPath = os.path.join(self.packageUid(), os.path.normpath(partial_url).lstrip("\\/"))
        # We create TabletService here in order to avoid
        # problems with connections and disconnections of the tablet during the life of the application
        return "http://%s/apps/%s" %(self._getTabletService().robotIp(), subPath.replace(os.path.sep, "/"))

    def onInput_onStart(self):
         # We create TabletService here in order to avoid
        # problems with connections and disconnections of the tablet during the life of the application
        tabletService = self._getTabletService()
        if tabletService:
            try:
                url = "http://www.google.com/"
                if url == '':
                    self.logger.error("URL of the image is empty")
                if not url.startswith('http'):
                    url = self._getAbsoluteUrl(url)
                self.logger.info(url)
                tabletService.showWebview(url)
            except Exception as err:
                self.logger.error("Error during ShowImage : %s " % err)
                self.onStopped()
        self.onStopped()
```